# If statement wrong syntax jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

---

I'm trying to implement a simple if/else statement in JavaScript but it's not working.

Can you tell me what is wrong with this syntax?

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {
      if ($(window).width() < 900);
        $(".stats").css("background-color", "red");
      else 
        $(".stats").css("background-color", "white");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove ; at the end of if condition

```
if ($(window).width() < 900)// here
```

if you want to change background color when windows is resizing use :

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width() < 900)
        $(".stats").css("background-color", "red");
      else 
        $(".stats").css("background-color", "white");
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tuCuj/)  (use center column to resize)

Comment: Thanks daguru, that's a really thorough answer.

Answer (score 5):

Remove `;` after your `if` statement:

```
if ($(window).width() < 900)
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `;` at the end of if statement.

```
if ($(window).width() < 900);
```

to

```
if ($(window).width() < 900)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize the statements with

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var color = $(window).width() < 900 ? "red" : "white";
       $(".stats").css("background-color", color);
});  
</script>
```

Fiddler for the same http://jsfiddle.net/b8zLw/